# Windows 7 NotifyIcon GUID spoof-protection

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, guid, notifyicon

I am currently working on learning some different aspects of WINAPI, including features introduced in windows 7.. One of those is using a GUID as identifier for a Notification icon.

As can be read on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940367%28VS.85%29.aspx#running), the GUID is bound to the executable by path, the first time the notification icon is added. This page in question promises further information on the issue at the documentation for Shell_Notifyicon(), but I cannot find any further information there.

How are users supposed to be able to display notification-icons from an executable that has been moved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773352%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> If the path must be changed, the
>   application should clear the existing
>   GUID registry information before
>   moving the binary file to a new
>   location and reregistering it with a
>   new GUID. Any settings associated with
>   the original GUID registration will be
>   lost.
>
> This also occurs in the case of a
>   side-by-side installation. When
>   dealing with a side-by-side
>   installation, new versions of the
>   application should update the GUID of
>   the binary file.
>
> Note  The only exception to a moved
>   file occurs when both the original and
>   moved binary files are
>   Authenticode-signed by the same
>   company. In that case, settings are
>   preserved through the move.

The mechanics of the app "clearing the existing GUID registry information" are bit, erm, unclear.  I'd work from the assumption that this doesn't actually happen often.  So, new guid or a certificate.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the location of this information, however there surely must be an easier way for the user to move the executable than having to ask the developer for a new build (or update the application.)

Comment: I'm trying to think back to the last time I moved an installed app.  No, my memory fails me.  That just doesn't work anymore these days.  Uninstall, re-install, the installer generates a new guid.  Not quite sure if I completely understand this, but surely the vendors that have to be worry about getting their notification icons spoofed already sign their apps.

Comment: The problem is that the icon will be associated with the directory in which you have built the application.